# Clone user input over multiple browser tabs for testing different languages

Tags: browser, automation, browser-addons

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to clone user input between multiple browser tabs/sessions.

I would like to be able to login to four accounts of my site in four different tabs. Set the language to four different languages. Then use a tool to replicate all my input between all the tabs. That way I can navigate in one tab and simply flick between the other tabs to check they are correct.

The session management part seems easy enough... I can not find a tool that synchronizes my user input between the tabs

Comment: And this tool/add-on should work on all browsers on every OS?

Comment: just an idea: http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/index.php

Comment: Browsers or OS I am not too bothered by. I can use a VM :)